# I can't do "sudo apt-get update" (malformed entry 54 in sources.list)

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-sources

I see there are some similar questions but there's no solution there for my case. At least none that I could understand.

When I type `sudo apt-get update`, I get a response:

```
E: Malformed entry 54 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: Nie udało się odczytać list źródeł.
```

Second line means that it was impossible to read the list of sources.

[Here is my /etc/apt/sources.list file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z037c8qxq3wmy04/sourceslist.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two lines in your sources.list file:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
```

should look like this:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
#deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Comment: You're very welcome.